# \varnothing does not work

Tags: bug, mathjax

I created a question with \varnothing to denote empty set.

In the preview it played nice, but on the question page \varnothing was replaced with \emptyset for some mysterious reason.

Why \varnothing does not work?

Comment: FWIW, it works at the sand box [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4993/21436).

Comment: It is displayed ok for me in your question [How is it called a minimal morphism of category Rel?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186384/how-is-it-called-a-minimal-morphism-of-category-rel)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: In this my question it looks for me as \emtpyset not \varnothing. It's weird that we see different things.

Comment: If there is a problem with the way something is displayed, then you should probably add a screenshot and mention which OS and browser you are using.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Firefox 14.0.1 Debian Linux. screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/lt0uo.png

Answer (score 4):

Testing:

varnothing $\varnothing$

emptyset $\emptyset$

Well, it seems to work for me. That's too bad.

Comment: I can confirm the "wrong" symbols (both Safari 5.1.7 and FF 14.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8): [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KviTE.png), while [the preview](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5W0oE.png) looks fine. Concerning differences between preview and actual post see Willie's comment [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928/nested-mathjax-environments-render-correctly-in-the-preview-but-are-broken-in-t#comment14704_3928). See also [my comment here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184943/which-symbol-should-be-used-for-an-empty-set#comment427055_184943) for ...

Comment: ... a manifestation of somewhat erratic behavior of $\varnothing$ and $\emptyset$ in comments. I noticed similar glitches with `\setminus` and `\smallsetminus` but can't remember an instance off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm also getting the symbols switched, both here and in the question and answer referenced by the OP (but not in the preview).

Comment: @t.b. `\setminus` shows up as a long backslash in preview but as a small backslash in the final post.

Comment: It looks like the difference people are seeing depends on whether they are using the STIX fonts or not.  With STIX fonts, the two macros are reversed.  I will look into it further.

Comment: OK, here's what I have found:  STIXGeneral has the glyph for `\varnothing` in the unicode position for U+2205 (EMPTY SET), while the glyph for `\emptyset` is in that position in STIXVariant.  MathJax sets things up to get the right one when STIX is used, but unfortunately there is a timing problem and the TeX input has run before the change is made, so the output is reversed.  But for previews, the TeXing occurs later, after the change is made, so it looks right.  I think `\setminus` is a similar problem.  I will look into fixing it for the next release of MathJax.

Comment: @Davide Makoto has [reported](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers#comment19789_4666) that our sandbox has become slower. Can you see anything there that might be slowing down MathJax? I presumed with the older answers deleted all would be well. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

MathJax v2.1 should resolve this issue. Math.SE is now using the beta version of MathJax v2.1, so you should see the correct rendering for these characters now (both the empty sets and the setminus issues should be fixed). Please let me know if that is not the case.

Note that if you keep your browser open continually, you may need to empty the cache and reload the page (or perhaps even restart the browser) to get the new copy of MathJax. (MathJax's About box should tell you which version you are getting; make sure all the files in the list show v2.1).

See [MathJax 2.1 beta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/mathjax-2-1-beta) for more details on the changes in MathJax v2.1.

Comment: As always, many thanks for MathJax support.